# Need documentation that describes the output of OpenGL's rotate method

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have created a custom cube whose sides can be removed. I would eventually like to print the cube to a paper printer. I would like to do my own rotation by using the output from the OpenGL rotate method.

My question: Does documentation exist that describes the Identity Matrix after a rotation? Or is the source available for the OpenGL rotate method?

Comment: Have you looked for documentation? There is a lot about OpenGL on the 'net.

Comment: There is a dedicated man page for *every* single OpenGL function from the stone-ages to GL 4.4.

Comment: I am currently performing many  matrix operations and am passing my FloatBuffer & rotated Model Matrix to the vertex and fragment shaders. But, as you know, they are responsible for the rasterization of my data to the screen. I need the rotation output so I can output to other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glRotate creates a rotation matrix and multiplies that in place on the matrix on top of the current matrix stack. Rotation matrices are a well known thing in linear algebra.

Comment: I am currently performing many matrix operations and am passing my FloatBuffer & rotated Model Matrix to the vertex and fragment shaders. But, as you know, they are responsible for the rasterization of my data to the screen. And I need to get at the rotated data for my output.

Comment: @user2588157: `glRotate` does nothing else than building a 4×4 rotation matrix and multiplying that onto the matrix on top of the current stack. It doesn't actually "rotate" anything. What you want is getting the transformed data back. You can either use *transform feedback* for this (which saves the output of the vertex state in buffer), or you reimplement the OpenGL transformation pipeline yourself.

Comment: @user2588157: You can find the definition of a rotation matrix in every linear algebra text book, and of course in the [OpenGL-2.1 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf) (p. 45).

Comment: comment about _transform feedback_ started me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Matrix calculations and Matrix Transformations all over the internet, here is a few links.

- [Matrix Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29)
- [Transformation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)
- [OpenGL Programming/3D/Matrices](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/3D/Matrices)

Though here is something I've created for calculating exactly what you're trying to calculate. There isn't much so explain because it is basically just a bunch of math formulas.

```
public class Matrix4
{
    public float m00, m01, m02, m03;
    public float m10, m11, m12, m13;
    public float m20, m21, m22, m23;
    public float m30, m31, m32, m33;

    public Matrix4()
    {
        this.set(
            1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
            0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
            0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    }

    public void rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
        float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);

        if ((x * x + y * y + z * z) != 1f)
        {
            float length = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

            if (length > 0f)
            {
                length = 1f / length;

                x *= length;
                y *= length;
                z *= length;
            }
        }

        this.mul(
            x * x * (1f - cos) + cos, x * y * (1f - cos) - z * sin, x * z * (1f - cos) + y * sin, 0f,
            y * x * (1f - cos) + z * sin, y * y * (1f - cos) + cos, y * z * (1f - cos) - x * sin, 0f,
            x * z * (1f - cos) - y * sin, y * z * (1f - cos) + x * sin, z * z * (1f - cos) + cos, 0f,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    }

    public void mul(
            float m00, float m01, float m02, float m03,
            float m10, float m11, float m12, float m13,
            float m20, float m21, float m22, float m23,
            float m30, float m31, float m32, float m33)
    {
        float mm00 = this.m00 * m00 + this.m01 * m10 + this.m02 * m20 + this.m03 * m30;
        float mm01 = this.m00 * m01 + this.m01 * m11 + this.m02 * m21 + this.m03 * m31;
        float mm02 = this.m00 * m02 + this.m01 * m12 + this.m02 * m22 + this.m03 * m32;
        float mm03 = this.m00 * m03 + this.m01 * m13 + this.m02 * m23 + this.m03 * m33;

        float mm10 = this.m10 * m00 + this.m11 * m10 + this.m12 * m20 + this.m13 * m30;
        float mm11 = this.m10 * m01 + this.m11 * m11 + this.m12 * m21 + this.m13 * m31;
        float mm12 = this.m10 * m02 + this.m11 * m12 + this.m12 * m22 + this.m13 * m32;
        float mm13 = this.m10 * m03 + this.m11 * m13 + this.m12 * m23 + this.m13 * m33;

        float mm20 = this.m20 * m00 + this.m21 * m10 + this.m22 * m20 + this.m23 * m30;
        float mm21 = this.m20 * m01 + this.m21 * m11 + this.m22 * m21 + this.m23 * m31;
        float mm22 = this.m20 * m02 + this.m21 * m12 + this.m22 * m22 + this.m23 * m32;
        float mm23 = this.m20 * m03 + this.m21 * m13 + this.m22 * m23 + this.m23 * m33;

        float mm30 = this.m30 * m00 + this.m31 * m10 + this.m32 * m20 + this.m33 * m30;
        float mm31 = this.m30 * m01 + this.m31 * m11 + this.m32 * m21 + this.m33 * m31;
        float mm32 = this.m30 * m02 + this.m31 * m12 + this.m32 * m22 + this.m33 * m32;
        float mm33 = this.m30 * m03 + this.m31 * m13 + this.m32 * m23 + this.m33 * m33;

        this.m00 = mm00; this.m01 = mm01; this.m02 = mm02; this.m03 = mm03;
        this.m10 = mm10; this.m11 = mm11; this.m12 = mm12; this.m13 = mm13;
        this.m20 = mm20; this.m21 = mm21; this.m22 = mm22; this.m23 = mm23;
        this.m30 = mm30; this.m31 = mm31; this.m32 = mm32; this.m33 = mm33;
    }

    public void set(
            float m00, float m01, float m02, float m03,
            float m10, float m11, float m12, float m13,
            float m20, float m21, float m22, float m23,
            float m30, float m31, float m32, float m33)
    {
        this.m00 = m00;
        this.m01 = m01;
        this.m02 = m02;
        this.m03 = m03;

        this.m10 = m10;
        this.m11 = m11;
        this.m12 = m12;
        this.m13 = m13;

        this.m20 = m20;
        this.m21 = m21;
        this.m22 = m22;
        this.m23 = m23;

        this.m30 = m30;
        this.m31 = m31;
        this.m32 = m32;
        this.m33 = m33;
    }
}
```

The following will create an Identity Matrix `Matrix4 m = new Matrix4();`

**Important** do notice that the angle given in the `rotate()` function in `Matrix4` is in **radians** where in OpenGL the `glRotate()` functions requires the angle to be in **degrees**.

Also if the Matrix is "opposite", when you are using it then simply before you use the Matrix for anything else calculate the [Transpose of the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), and then you can use it.

Comment: I think that you understand my problem. I am currently performing many  matrix operations and am passing my FloatBuffer & rotated Model Matrix to the vertex and fragment shaders. But, as you know, they are responsible for the rasterization of my data to the screen.     Thanks for the code, but unfortunately, the code you posted had a compile error at "this.mul(...);" and I can't fix it. Can you help?

Comment: @user2588157 probably because you're using another language than I'm using in the answer. Which language do you use?

Comment: @user2588157 the code is in Java as well, and I just realized that I copied the wrong method from my code, I've added the correct one now, so it will work if copy all the code now.

Comment: I copied the new code, but now it fails in methods public void mul(...) & public void set(...) with "Cannot resolve symbols".  Every "this.mXX" is flagged. As before, I tried to fix it but I can't.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user2588157 Ohh god I suck at copying code. Though I added the missing code, it really should work now. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, the code compiles successfully. But, I guess I don't know how to invoke the code. In MainActivity I coded:                             "float angle = 1.5705f;  float x = 2.0f;  float y = 0.0f;  float z = 0.0f;  Matrix4 m = new Matrix4();  Matrix4.rotate(angle, x, y, z);". I received the error "Non-static method 'Matrix4.rotate(angle, x, y, z);' cannot be referenced from a static context" in MainActivity. Upon trying to change "public void rotate" returns the error "this.mul" "cannot be referenced from a static context".  I must have not invoked the rotate method properly. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not a static method so you need to call `m.rotate(angle, x, y, z);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, you and datenwolf are my new favorite coders. Thanks, again.